# Why Eclipse complains to remove main/ from java build path?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, directory, m2e

I have the following error when I try to update maven dependencies from Eclipse (using `mvn -U` is working fine):

```
Cannot nest 'project_name-web/src/main/resources' inside 'project_name-web/src'. To enable the nesting exclude 'main/' from 'project_name-web/src'
```

When I go at `Java Build Path` I have only `project_name-web/src` at it. As pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15411137/3026886) I don't have any `sourceDirectory` tag at `pom.xml`. Considering [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35556852/3026886), I would like to know why/where I should use this method to solve my problem since `src/main/resources` is inside `/src`. Why just `main/` is required to be removed from JBP since it's this folder which has all `.java` files?

Here's my project directory tree (names omitted for security):

[image]

Comment: Your configuration sounds wrong...can you show the directory structure you have ?

Comment: Done, @khmarbaise

Comment: Eclipse seems to think "src" is your source root, whereas it should actually be "src/main/java". I seem to recall there's a context menu item called `Maven -> Update Project Configuration` or similar. That should help fix it.

Comment: Ah, this is it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13726968/342852

Comment: Thanks @SeanPatrickFloyd for the clarification at this silly mistake. I already marked this question as duplicate of your link. It worked